# reverse bits in Java - O(n)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, reverse, bit

I'm trying to understand this code which reverses bits in O(n) time. I understand the time complexity, but I'm not able to understand the logic behind this code.

```
public static long reverse(long a) {
    long result = 0;
    int i = 31;
    while(a > 0){

        result += (a % 2) * Math.pow(2, i);
        i--;                        
        a = a/2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

To keep it simple, for example, if I take 12 (1100) and only 4 bits (set i = 3), my output will be 3 (0011). I get that and I'm able to derive the answer as well.

But can someone explain the logic behind this code? Thanks!

Comment: Strange to call this O(log n), since I would rather call the number of bits, i, the problem size, and then it is O(i).

Comment: @Harald I think he refers to the runtime complexity.

Comment: @Harald you're right, number of bits is the input size, and that makes it `O(n)`

Comment: sorry, updated it with O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the explanation

```
i = 31 //number of bits in integer
```

Following has two parts

```
result += (a % 2) * Math.pow(2, i);
```

`(a % 2)` calculates last bit.
 Multiplying anything with a positive power of `2` has the effect of left shifting the bits. (`Math.pow(2, i)` shifts to left `i` times.

so we are calculating unit place bit and placing it at ith position from the unit place, which is `(31 - i)` from the right, which effectively reverses the bit's position from left to right.

and finally

```
i--; //move to next bit
a = a/2; //chop the unit place bit to proceed to next.
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

That code is

1. broken for half the possible bit patterns (all the negative numbers), and
2. O(n), not O(log n), where n is the number of bits in `a`
3. Very inefficient
4. Confusingly written

The algorithm works only for positive numbers and does:

```
extract the rightmost bit from a
set the corresponding bit from the left end
shift a one position to the right
```

It repeats as long as `a > 0`.  If the value of `a` has some leading zero bits then this algorithm will be a little better than O(n).

Inefficiency results from remainder and division for bit extraction when masking and shifting would be much faster, although a modern compiler *should* be able to convert `a/2` to `a >> 1` and `a%2` to `a & 0x00000001`.  However I don't know if it would recognize `Math.pow(2, i)` as `0x00000001 << i`;